# Relation for the determinant of a special Hadamard product.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, hadamard-product, circulant-matrices

Inspired by [this very related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676190/prove-that-beginvmatrix-xaybzc-yczaxb-zbxcya-endvmatrix-xyz-b).

Let $A$ be a circulant matrix and $X$ an anti-circulant matrix of size $n\times n$. Moreover let the sum of each row in $X$ be zero, $\sum_i x_{ij}=0$. It appears that for $n=3$, Oppenheim's inequality achieves equality, i.e.:
$$\det(A\circ X)= (\det A)\prod_i x_{ii}$$

Where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product.

Empirically, this relation no longer holds for other $n$. Is there a particular reason why this only works for $n=3$ and not for higher $n$? Is this just chance or is there a deeper reason?